# How about a 'resource' tab?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq

Their is a lot of information on Buddhism (in the broadest sense), in different languages and when translated often multiple times.

Since the users here are dedicated, I thought it might help (whomever) to get some resources/references easier. Be it like a sandbox of different material. Either to kick-start understanding of Buddhism, or background material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about amending the help page to include some useful resources? I've just found out that moderators can edit some of the sections. I've mocked up how the help page might look. This seems like a good place to put up helpful links and resources and we could direct new users to them to give them a head start.

What do we think?

[image]

Comment: I think this is a great idea. This way we will have a dedicated "ressource tab" and not a lot of lists and materials that are scattered throughout Buddhism SE. This could especially help new comers gain a better overview. How do we ensure that people get knowledge about this Ressource tab. Could we have a link on the front page, e.g. in "featured on meta" box? Then we could have both the Ressource tab + the Guidelines for new users next to each other.

Comment: @Lanka I'm thinking that we feature it for a bit in the meta box as you say. Then we can start to include the link in comments to new users as well - Robin was very good at posting comments to newcomers so we could borrow and adapt her text maybe.

Comment: Great idea. We can also update the New User Welcome to add in a suggestion to visit this section and a link to it. :)

Comment: That (Help) page can only be edited by moderators. Depending on whether anyone should be able to edit it, and on how big it should be, if you wanted to make a user-editable page you could create it as a new topic/page on the main site (make it "community wiki" probably); and edit that help page you suggested only once, to make it include one link to the new 'Resources' page/topic.

Comment: I'd say that's a good start! Perhaps I should also, but then even more general, propose it to StackExchange itself. But if we can make it happen here, the GUI can always be upgraded later on

Comment: @ChrisW I like the idea of a set of links on that page that we agree on (with a meta question or two) that can then be edited by mods as required. It's more 'one click' and one we decide it shouldn't change much. People can always request extra links through meta. I will start a new thread though to propose the detail of it

Comment: @Everyone. Sounds like a good idea and thanks Robin for making your texts available. Do we know when the ressource tab will be made and is any help needed?

Comment: @Lanka - I've just put on a start [here](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help). I'll open up a thread when I get a minute asking for ideas about content

Comment: @Crab. Good job. I like it so far. You could also add these websites: [The Thirty-one Planes of Existence](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html), [Schools of Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schools_of_Buddhism), [Triple Refuge](http://www.yellowrobe.com/practice/the-triple-refugee/215-how-to-take-the-triple-refuge.html) & [Five Precepts](http://www.yellowrobe.com/practice/the-five-precepts/216-what-are-the-five-precepts-and-how-to-take-it.html). Only if you have the time.