# Suggestions for resources section

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Leading on from [this question](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1614/157) we are starting to put together a resources section under the [help section](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help). The idea is that we can collect some generally useful resources in this section and redirect new (and old) users to them to assist in asking and answering questions. Unfortunately the help section is only editable by moderators - so I'm asking what resources people would like under this section.

[image]

I've made a start by adding a few links with the help of [Lanka](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/2424/lanka). Let me know if the links are OK or not or you want a change in wording. Also, if you think this is an terrible idea or would like to do it differently then please let me know.

Comment: I think this looks great. Good job. I will post some links in an answer.

Comment: Update: The Resource section has grown a lot. I'm happy to see that. Good job to everyone for making this happen.

Answer (score 4):

[The Thirty-one Planes of Existence](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html) - a quick overview of the different planes of existence. Comes in handy when studying the texts and there is a reference to a realm.

[Schools of Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schools_of_Buddhism) - a wikipedia-overview of the different schools in Buddhism.

[How to take the triple refuge](http://www.yellowrobe.com/practice/the-triple-refugee/215-how-to-take-the-triple-refuge.html) - useful for new comers who wants to learn how to take refuge in the triple gem.

[How to take the 5 precepts](http://www.yellowrobe.com/practice/the-five-precepts/216-what-are-the-five-precepts-and-how-to-take-it.html) - also aimed at new comers who wants to learn how to take the five precepts.

[Vipassana 10-day Goenka Retreat Locations](https://www.dhamma.org/en/locations/directory#dk) - For practitioners that would like to go on retreat. This is the 10-day Goenka retreat and the different locations where its being held.

[Fundamentals in Buddhism](http://www.buddhanet.net/fundbud.htm) - for the new comer who wants to learn about Buddhism. In here is the basic doctrines covered, such as *The Buddha, The Four Noble Truths, The Noble Eightfold Path, Kamma, 3 Characteristics etc.*

[The Buddhist Publication Society](http://www.bps.lk) - for authentic literature on Buddhism. The Buddhist Publication Society (BPS), founded in Sri Lanka in 1958, is an approved charity dedicated to making known the teaching of the Buddha.

[Free Books by Mahasi Sayadaw](http://www.yellowrobe.com/books/mahasi-sayadaw/237-books-by-mahasi-sayadaw.html) - for practitioners following the Mahasi Sayadaw Tradition. In here you can find books by Mahasi Sayadaw on topics such as *Vipassana techniques, different suttas, progress of insight, dependent origination and more*.

[Benefits of Walking Meditation](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/silananda/bl137.html) - for meditators who are practicing walking meditation or wants to learn it. Here is a great article on it by Ven. Sayadaw U Silananda.

[Sets of the Pāli Canon in English Translation and in Pāli (Tipiṭaka)](http://www.palitext.com/palitext/tipitaka.htm) - here one can get a set of the tipitaka in english or pali.

[Video Abhidhamma Retreat with Ven. Bhikkhu Bodhi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSL1N5caXZM) - here one can follow Ven. Bhikkhu Bodhi's Abhidhamma Retreat. The whole retreat is divided into 15 videos with a length of approx 1 hour.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added your links. Let me know if I've missed anything.

Comment: This looks great. I like how you organized it into sections. This ressource will become very important for Buddhism SE. I imagine when more and more is getting added we will have our own encyclopedia and go-to-library. Amazing. Thanks for putting your time and effort into this.

Comment: No problem at all. It wasn't hard to be honest. If you want anything else on just let me know. Metta

Answer (score 3):

### http://suttacentral.net

> SuttaCentral includes detailed references, shows relationships between texts in diverse collections, and, where possible, provides original text and translations.
>
> Texts include the Pali canon of the Theravāda school, which we have in both modern translations and the original Pali. SuttaCentral also provides the early Āgama texts from the Taishō edition of the Chinese canon, as well as references for the Tibetan Kangyur, Sanskrit, and other languages, which are much smaller in number than the Pali and Chinese collections.
>
> SuttaCentral offers extensive resources on the Buddhist monastic code (Vinaya), with texts, translations, and some 14,000 parallels. We also cover the canonical Abhidhamma texts, which provide a detailed analytical treatment of the central doctrines.

### http://www.dhammawheel.com/

> A Buddhist discussion forum on the Dhamma of the Theravada

### http://www.buddhanet.net

> BuddhaNet is a not-for-profit organisation affiliated with the Buddha Dharma Education Association Inc, which was first established as a Vipassana Meditation Centre in 1992 in Sydney by an Australian meditation monk Ven. Pannyavaro. BDEA has since evolved as a Buddhist Information and Education Service.

Plus lots of free e-books.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added your links. Let me know if I've missed anything.

Answer (score 3):

There's also http://dharmawheel.net/ which seem to be the corresponding mahayana forum (just as dhammawheel is for theravada)

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added it

Answer (score 3):

I found two more links for the Resource Section:

- [Acinteyya - The Four Imponderables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acinteyya#Four_imponderables)
- [Satta Bojjhaṅgā - Seven Factors of Enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Factors_of_Enlightenment)

Comment: Apologies - completely forgot about it. I've put them on now. Thanks for the additional ones and sorry for the delay. Cheers

Comment: No worries and no stress. There is not deadline here. Relax and be well. Thanks for putting the links up.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/ has the story as well as each verse.

http://www.buddha-vacana.org/ has Pali next to English for several suttas; combine that with a http://dsal.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/pali/ (because often a sutta depends on the meaning of a word).

Several web sites (each with many books) were mentioned in the [Dharma Books](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16470/dharma-books) chat room.

Wikipedia describes four noble truths, noble eightfold path, four stages of enlightenment, five precepts, etc.

There are several introductory books that people have recommended e.g. *In the Buddha's Words*, etc.

Many of the questions on the main site may be helpful for beginners (e.g. [this one](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4112/254)).

Maybe http://www.realbuddhaquotes.com/ instead of http://fakebuddhaquotes.com/

Some questions (especially FAQs) are answered by [Yuttadhammo's videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/yuttadhammo).

Comment: For Venerable Yuttadhammo's videos, his [Q & A Video Wiki](http://video.sirimangalo.org/) is a bit easier to navigate as all questions are categorized.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added your links. Let me know if I've missed anything.

Answer (score 2):

Ven. Yuttadhammo mentioned in one of his talks that a good reference for The Jakataka Tales is this website: [Sacred Texts](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/index.htm).

In here one can find all volumes of the Jataka.

Comment: I've popped it up. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Following may be a good addition also.

Meditation centres:

- [International Meditation Centre in the tradition of Sayagyi U Ba Khin](http://www.internationalmeditationcentre.org/global/index.html)
- [Meditation Centres in Achan Cha Tradition](https://forestsangha.org/)
- [Pa Auk Monasteries](http://www.paaukforestmonastery.org/contact.htm)

Books:

- [Forest Dhamma Books](http://www.forestdhamma.org/books/english/) - Books in the tradition of [Ajahn Mun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mun_Bhuridatta)
- [Abhidhamma](http://abhidhamma.com/) - the third division of the Pāḷi canon or Tipiṭaka (three baskets)
- [Dhamma Talks](http://www.dhammatalks.net/) - transcriptions of talks by many authors and speakers
- [Dhamma Talks of Thanissaro Bhikkhu](http://www.dhammatalks.org/) - from the *Kammatthana* (or Thai Forest) Tradition of Buddhism.

  - [Free Books by Pariyatti](https://store.pariyatti.org/Free-Products_c_421.html)
- [Corporate Body of the Buddha Educational Foundation](http://www.budaedu.org/en/book/)
- Inward Path Publications
- WAVE Publication - hockchai2009@yahoo.com
- Selangor Buddhist Vipassana Meditation Society (SBVMS) - sbvms@yahoo.com

Tripitaka Translations:

- [The Dharmafarers](http://dharmafarer.org/wordpress/) - in-depth analysis of suttas.
- [Abhidhamma](http://abhidhamma.com/) - the third division of the Pāḷi canon or Tipiṭaka (three baskets)

Comment: Maybe we shouldn't have (should remove) all Meditation and Retreat Centres (including the 3 which are currently on http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help)? Because there are so many of them and if we start we wouldn't know where to stop? Or we should only include any directories (lists) of centres rather than individual centres? E.g. http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/ has 7,500 entries, world-wide.

Comment: Maybe we can include ones with a multiple branches and wide outreach.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see an article on how to cite and how to decipher citations to the Pali Canon. I suggested this directly to Buddhism: Stack Exchange and received a rather strange reply by email that suggested that the answerer didn't understand what I was suggesting, so I am suggesting it here (having just found this area).

Comment: I think Crab Bucket was asking, what links to existing resources/articles do you suggest we add [to this list](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) because they're helpful? Re. how to cite the canon, there's [an answer here](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/8566/254) about how suttas are numbered if that's what you're asking. IMO the clearest way to cite the Pali canon (if it's online) is using a hyperlink: I tend to use name of sutta + sutta number + hyperlink [for example here](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/18069/254).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/ seems like a useful resource.

You could describe it as, "World Buddhist Directory - may be helpful when you're looking for local communities."