# How do you create Community Wiki Questions?

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

When postings answers there is a check box for community Wiki answers. If you are posting a question how can this be made Community Wiki question as such checkbox does not appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The current list**

The following search finds all our current CW topics: "[wiki:1 is:question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+is%3Aquestion)"
(see also, [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)).

---

**Moderators**

Making a question CW is something which moderators (but, now, only moderators) can do (moderators see the CW checkbox available when they edit a topic).

(Until 2010 users could mark their own questions as CW -- [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55888/139866) -- but they changed that, e.g. because it caused arguments, like "your question is slightly off-topic, so, you must mark it as CW").

---

**Examples on other sites**

CW is and should be used rarely. It's mostly intended for collaborative topics, where there's not one best answer -- for example,

- [Dictionary of regional vocabulary differences (US vs UK)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/5343/1097)

  This is one answer edited 10 times over more than 2 years
- [Terminology index - a list of bike part names and cycling concepts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/244/1097)

  This is many, separate answers; with an alphabetically-sorted list of links to each answer edited into the topic's "question".

Or for example there's,

- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/49942)

  This is so popular that it's CW and locked, edited nearly 100 times, and can now only be changed by their moderators (and, I guess but don't know, might have caused some disagreement if everyone tried to add their favourite book or the latest book to the list).

---

**CW on this site**

This site has a few CW topics. They are listed here:

- [Current list of all CW topics](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+is%3Aquestion)

Another example of something *like* CW is our,

- [Useful resources](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) (which were [created collaboratively](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1616/254))

CW is a bit useless if it's not a collaborative effort. If there's a CW topic you'd like to create, perhaps post it here on meta first as a proposal.

Note that this site isn't really meant to be a wiki ... not trying to compete with Wikipedia.

Another time when CW might be useful is when nearly-the-same question is being asked by different people again and again -- because they're nearly the same they ought to be in one place, because they're not quite the same the answer might need to be more detailed/inclusive/edited to account for the various difference.

Comment: OK. Great. Can you make this a CW if appropriate according to the above posts: [What are good Buddhist Blogs / articles sites / resource sites out there?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13472/what-are-good-buddhist-blogs-articles-sites-resource-sites-out-there)

Comment: Done. Sorry for the lengthy reply, I hadn't understood why you were asking.

Comment: Good for future reference.