# How about a resource pool?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have often seen that new people who just join ask for Books,Abhidhamma explanations,Meditation teaching audios & etc.

And every time a person tries to answer these question he has to go all over the internet to find links,articles,videos,etc.

---

So what i'm asking is can we build a resource pool like a blog or a cloud that people can have access to. People who wants to answer questions will add the links from there without any hassle as everything is there in one place and readers can take whatever they want just the same.

Answer (score 1):

There's a list of (some) useful resources on [the site's Help page](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help).

See also [Suggestions for resources section](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1616/254).